# Modificar o Paginate no Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Boa noite pessoal!
Eu estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta utilizando o Laravel. Talvez eu ainda tenha que estudar mais para poder alcançar um nível de conhecimento para poder discutir melhor sobre isso, pois eu não sou desenvolvedor, mas graças a Deus eu tenho aprendido tudo o que estou precisando para conseguir fazer o que eu preciso.

A minha dúvida é:
- Como eu consigo alterar a quantidade de páginas exibidas em uma tabela? Atualmente minhas páginas exibem tabelas com o padrão de 10 itens. Eu gostaria de alterar esse padrão, mudar de 10 itens para 30 para facilitar a experiência do usuário.

Para ajudar a esclarecer minha dúvida, segue a imagem abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que o tempo de cada um é precioso, se puderem talvez me indicarem alguns links ou dar uma dica de como poderei seguir... Eu agradeço imensamente! Obrigado!

Comment: seja bem vindo! tenta seguir esses passos para sua pergunta ser mais clara para todos aqui. leia com atenção https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1 espero que a resposta que coloquei abaixo ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para alterar a **quantidade** a ser exibida crie uma variável em seu **controller**

```
protected $totalPaginas = 30;
```

então um exemplo poderia ser sua pagina index, que eu **suponho** que poderia trazer todas os resultados do retorno consultado.

```
public function index()
    {
        $varParaEnviarParaView = $this->minhaModelFiltrada->paginate($this->totalPaginas);
        return view('caminho.para.minha.view', compact("varParaEnviarParaView"));
    }
```

o método paginate retorna a quantidade de páginas.

por último em sua view acrescente ao final da página, **fora do foreach**

```
{{$varParaEnviarParaView->links()}}
```

acredito que resolva a questão.

Comment: André! Não sei como te agradecer... Obrigado pela orientação em me enviar o link de boas práticas com as perguntas, sou novo aqui e peço desculpas se cometi algum erro. Mas você entendeu a minha dúvida, inclusive me passou tudo de "mão beijada" e deu certo por aqui. Poxa, obrigado mesmo! Sucesso, que Deus abençoe.

Comment: que bom que deu certo! ;)